# Multiple Pointer Test in If Statement

Tags: c, null, pointers, testing

considering a pointer to a struct

```
struct a_struct  
{   
    int A; 
};
```

Is it ok to do :

```
struct a_struct *ptr;  

//...

if( ptr != NULL && ptr->A == 1)  
{  
    //work with ptr struct  
}
```

or should you Test if the pointer is valid before testing for on of its field.

```
if(ptr != NULL)
{
    if(ptr->A == 1)
    {
        //work with ptr struct
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that's ok.

The `&&` operator short-circuits in C, so `ptr->A == 1` will only be evaluated if `ptr` is non-null.

Answer (score 5):

`&&` evaluates the second test only if the first was successful, so your code (*one* `if` statement) is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

That will work, and is actually a fairly common idiom. If you write an `else` clause, you do have to worry about which check kicked you there, but that is no different from any other mult-condition `if`-check.